# Bluetooth message application with delay

Tags: android, bluetooth, dtn

I've been trying to build an app for several weeks already, but it's taking me nowhere and I feel that I'm wasting my time so I come here to ask for your help.

The application should do this:

- Connect Phone A to Phone B using bluetooth
- The 2 phones should be able to send messages to each other
- If not within range, save the message and hold it until the other phone is within range.

I've read a lot about this subject and I think I'm going to use the BluetoothChat sample and modify it so it can do what I want.

I wonder if such an app is possible and how can I approach it using the BluetoothChat sample code?